# How much is one obligated to hold a will?

Tags: halacha, death

This is a completely uncharted area for me.

For example, a father requests his sons to continue a business, or to stay in the same town, or not to leave the country, or to wear white socks, or to call a grandson in his name etc. Something that does not relate straight to father's good, unlike learning Torah in his memory.

To what extent is father's will (non-monetary requests) obligatory for his sons? Is it Halachicly equal to requesting while alive? Do the same Halachic principles apply?

The Gemmarah (Gittin 14b) vaguely mentions that fulfillment of a will is a Mitzvah but in some specific monetary context (thank yO):

> "ר' יהודה הנשיא אמר משום ר' יעקב שאמר משום ר"מ **מצוה לקיים דברי המת**"

What the parent can and cannot obligate the kids to do after their passing away?

Comment: IOW what are the limits of מצוה לשמוע? or the limits of כיבוד אב?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I didn't see mentioning the will in all discussions on Kibud Av. Therefore I didn't link it to it. Where is it mentioned at all?

Comment: See Kitzur SA  26:22 for example: וְיֵשׁ לוֹ לָאָדָם לְצַוּוֹת אֵת בָּנָיו לְהַחְזִיק בְּאֵיזֹה מִצְוָה - though you sort of excluded this case.